# Gaussian tail inequality proof

Tags: probability

I am working independently through lecture notes on probability inequalities: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf

I would like to understand the steps in the proof of Theorem 1.

We have:

$\begin{align} \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} s \phi(s) ds = -\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \phi'(s)ds \end{align}$

To get the RHS I guess I need to use integration by parts but I don't know how to set it up using the formula:

$\begin{align} \int fg' = fg - \int f'g \end{align}$

When I tried with $g' = s$, I get:

$\begin{align} \frac{1}{\epsilon} \left[\frac{s^2}{2} \phi(s)\right]_{\epsilon}^{\infty} - \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{s^2}{2} \phi'(s) ds \end{align}$

When I tried the other way, I get the CDF $\Phi(s)$, which I don't think can be correct. Please tell me what I did wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't have $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ in your first equation.  And in fact, the first equation follows from $\phi'(s)=-s\,\phi(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Batominovski noted,$$\phi(s):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{s^2}{2}\implies\phi^\prime=-s\phi\implies\int_\epsilon^\infty s\phi(s)ds=-\int_\epsilon^\infty\phi^\prime(s)ds,$$so we don't need the $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ factor. In fact, the original file notes that$$\int_\epsilon^\infty\phi(s)ds\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_\epsilon^\infty s\phi(s)ds=-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_\epsilon^\infty\phi^\prime(s)ds.$$